# Why is my NSDateFormatter returning nil?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

lastReviewDate = "2016-06-06T20:24:15.9313557Z"

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
    let date = formatter.dateFromString(lastReviewDate)
```

date always returns nil. Why is this happening, it looks like my format matches the string exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"hh" be used with AM or PM, so if you want to use 0-23 hour , you have to use "HH" or you want 1-24 hour then use "kk"

Use this dateformat string it will be work

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'"

check this document

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html